# cannot resolve ActivityMainBinding in android studio 4.0

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-studio-4.0

I updated Android Studio from 3.6 to 4.0. Data Binding was working properly in 3.6 and working properly with the existing code in 4.0. But in 4.0  when I try to create new MainActivity (xml: activity_main), I am not getting the reference to ActivityMainBinding. Thought I am getting the reference to ActivityMainBindingImpl.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File->Invalidate Caches/Restart

if still does not work Build the .apk file

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try invalidate caches/restart
if this does not work try doing below code in your xml file

```
    <data class="NewActivityMainBinding">

        <variable
            name=""
            type="" />

    </data>
```

and use NewActivityMainBinding in your java/kt file